# Why is my client component unable to retrieve the correct error that was thrown from my server action?

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js14, react-server-components, server-action

I have a client component Form (`activate-form.tsx`) for new users to attach a username and name to their account when they first log in and authorize the app via NextAuth's Google OAuth provider.

I'm using Next.js, and the Form calls the server action (`activate()`) in an onSubmit handler which then calls NextAuth's `signIn()` function.

**activate-form.tsx**

```
// activate-form.tsx

// ...some code

const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = (values) => {
  const { username, name } = values;

  startTransition(() => {
    actions.activate(username, name).then((res) => {
      setError(res?.error);
    });
  });
};

return (

// ...some addtl code

<Form {...form}>
  <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-6">
    // ...rest of the Form
  />
</Form>

);
```

**auth.ts** - this is a separate file for my auth-related server actions

```
// auth.ts

// ...some code

export const activate = async (username: string, name: string) => {
  cookies().set('username', username);
  cookies().set('name', name);

  try {
    await auth.signIn('google');
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      return {
        error: error.message, // ** <== THIS IS WHERE NEXT_REDIRECT GETS RETURNED TO THE FORM **
      };
    }
  }
};
```

The `signIn()` function comes from NextAuth after initializing it with the PrismaAdapter.

**The problem** - I'm trying to catch errors that arise from the NextAuth signIn flow and return `error.message` to the Form where it can display the corresponding message from the actual error. But when an error gets caught, rather than giving me the expected `error.message`, I'm getting `”NEXT_REDIRECT”`.

For example, I want to override PrismaAdapter's `createUser` function so that I can execute some logic before creating the user. If i just throw any error in there, I expect to catch it from the signIn() call inside my server action, but I still get the “NEXT_REDIRECT” as the error message.

```
export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth((req) => ({
  adapter: {
    ...PrismaAdapter(db),
    async createUser(user) {
      throw new Error('testing testing'); <=== THROWN TO SEE IF SERVER ACTION PICKS IT UP

      // ...plan to add more logic here

      return user;
    },
  },
```

What's weird is that although `error.message` is “NEXT_REDIRECT” when I console.log it inside the catch block of the server action, if I were to instead re-throw the error I'm actually able to see the expected error and message in the server logs.

**modified auth.ts**

```
export const activate = async (username: string, name: string) => {
  cookies().set('username', username);
  cookies().set('name', name);

  try {
    await auth.signIn('google');
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      throw error // ** <=== RETHROW ERROR INSTEAD OF RETURNING IT
    }
  }
};
```

[image: server log]

Notice how `AdapterError` is showing along with the "testing testing" message from the error thrown from the `createUser` function.

***Why is it that when I rethrow the error it's correct, but when I log it inside the server action I just get “NEXT_REDIRECT”?*** And how can I get the proper message back to the Form?